# Creating a ListView with JQuery mobile doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile, dynamic

Using JQuery mobile I want to add a ul-ListView to a window dynamically creating it via JScript, there is a problem.

When I add the ListView fixed to HTML, everything works fine. The definition looks like

```
    ...            
        <div data-role=content>
             <ul id='listviewAktuelleChecklist' data-role=listview data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset=true>
                <li id="listDividerAktuelleChecklist" data-role=list-divider>yyy Checklist</li>
                <li id='LoadChecklist'> <a> Checkliste von Market-Value laden </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   ...
```

and when showing in Firefox its just what was expected. But when I create it by JScript, it looks like that:

(sorry guys, I'm not allowed to add a picture here due to missing references, so heres a link to the picture:
http://www.market-value.de/downloads/ul.jpg

The top ListView is what I get via the HTML definition, below the "OK" button what was generated (for those who don't view the picture: the generated Listviw shows just as a normal HTML "ul" with bullets...)

I used that code:

```
$("#BTN1").bind  ("click", function (event)
{
 var html = "";
 html += "<ul id='ChecklistListea' data-role=listview data-theme='d' data-divider-theme='d' data-inset=true>"
 html += '<li id="listDividerAktuelleChecklista" data-role=list-divider>yyy Checklist</li>'
 html +=   "<li id='LoadChecklista'> <a> Checkliste laden </a></li>";
 html += "</ul>";
 $(html).appendTo('#DivChecklistListe');

    $("#ChecklistListe").listview("refresh");

});
```

I tried some different methods for creating the dynamic HMTL, but the result was always the same.

Does anyone knows, what is going wrong here?

ps: if I define the ListView in HMTL directly and only add the ListItems everything works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are calling refresh on a wrong id, but even in case of a correct id this will not work. This is because you are creating a listview from scratch, ul element with inner li elements.

In this case it is not enough to call listview('refresh') because listview first must be initialized before it can be refreshed.

It can be done like this:

```
$("#ChecklistListea").listview().listview("refresh");
```

First **`.listview()`** call will initialize a listview and second one will style it.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/4HRNK/

Comment: Great! Thank you, this did the job! I should have been asking earlier, i could have saved 2 days...