# Creating a ListView with JQuery mobile doesn't work correctly II

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile, dynamic

Sorry to bother you again, but ran into another problem with that ListView. The answer of Gajotres ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741742/creating-a-listview-with-jquery-mobile-doesnt-work-correctly)) worked of course, but indeed my code ist a bit more complex: the ListView I mentioned is in a dynamically created popup. And there "new" refresh does not help. My code:

```
   var HlpStr =  'Wählen Sie die Checklist, die Sie laden wollen, durch Anklicken aus. '
            + '\n\nDer Download wird über die Schaltfläche "Checkliste laden" gestartet.' 
            + '\n\n Sie müssen mit dem Internet verbunden sein, um die Registrierung auszuführen!';

var html = "";
html += '<div data-role=header  data-theme="d">';
html +=   '<h1>Market-Value Checkliste laden</h1>';   
html += '</div>';

html += '<div data-role=content>';
html +=    '<p>' +  HlpStr + '</p>'; 
html +=    '<p> </p>'; 
html +=    "<ul id='ChecklistListex' data-role=listview data-theme='d' data-divider-theme='d' data-inset=true>";
html +=       '<li id="listDividerAktuelleChecklistx" data-role=list-divider>yyy Checklist</li>';
html +=       "<li id='LoadChecklistx'> <a> Checkliste laden </a></li>";
html +=    "</ul>"
html +=    '<p> </p>'; 
html +=    '<a id=BTNChecklisteLaden data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" >Checkliste laden</a>';      
html +=    '<a id=BTNChecklisteLadenAbbrechen data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" >abbrechen</a>';      
html += '</div>';

    var $popUp = $('<div align="center" />').popup({
        id : "DialogChecklistLaden",
        dismissible : false,
        theme : "b",
        positionTo : "window",
        tolerance : "30,40",
        overlayTheme : "b",
        transition : "pop",
        "data-add-back-btn": "true"
    }).bind("popupafterclose", 
       function() {
                    //remove the popup when closing
           $(this).remove();
    });
    $(html).appendTo($popUp);    
    $popUp.popup("open").trigger("create");
```

And here is what i get: [see picture here http://www.market-value.de/downloads/ul.jpg](http://www.market-value.de/downloads/PoppUpUL.jpg)

What I have to du to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me talk about your question. Before showing popup you should append it to page content. Mainly because **`trigger('create')`** is used on content DIV and no point on using it on anything else. In this case popup needs to be a part of a page for **`trigger('create')`** to work correctly. While **`trigger('create')`** can work outside content div using it on a data-role="content" is a safe move.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WC6ud/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    var html = "";
    html += '<div data-role=header  data-theme="d">';
    html +=   '<h1>Market-Value Checkliste laden</h1>';   
    html += '</div>';

    html += '<div data-role=content>';
    html +=    '<p>Meh</p>'; 
    html +=    '<p> </p>'; 
    html +=    "<ul id='ChecklistListex' data-role=listview data-theme='d' data-divider-theme='d' data-inset=true>";
    html +=       '<li id="listDividerAktuelleChecklistx" data-role=list-divider>yyy Checklist</li>';
    html +=       "<li id='LoadChecklistx'> <a> Checkliste laden </a></li>";
    html +=    "</ul>"
    html +=    '<p> </p>'; 
    html +=    '<a id=BTNChecklisteLaden data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" >Checkliste laden</a>';      
    html +=    '<a id=BTNChecklisteLadenAbbrechen data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" >abbrechen</a>';      
    html += '</div>';

    var $popUp = $('<div align="center" />').popup({
        id : "DialogChecklistLaden",
        dismissible : false,
        theme : "b",
        positionTo : "window",
        tolerance : "30,40",
        overlayTheme : "b",
        transition : "pop",
        "data-add-back-btn": "true"
    }).bind("popupafterclose", 
            function() {
                //remove the popup when closing
                $(this).remove();
            });
    $(html).appendTo($popUp);    
    $popUp.appendTo('#DivChecklistListe');
    $('#DivChecklistListe').trigger('create');
    $('#DialogChecklistLaden').popup("open");
});
```

Comment: No, no, you are right about accepting the answer. I'm myself activ in a Delphi forum and I apriciate it. I looked for, but didn't find anything to do so. As I know now, I was to fast... This time I immediately saw the "checker". And now for my problem: does this mean that I have to "anchor" the popup in a "div" in my main html (#DivChecklistListe in this case)?